# How can I iterate over a map with a pair as key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, output, stdmap

I have a `map` with a `pair<int, int>` as key and a third integer as value. How can I iterate over the map's keys in order to print them? My example code is pasted below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  map <pair<int, int>, int> my_map;
  pair <int, int> my_pair;

  my_pair = make_pair(1, 2);
  my_map[my_pair] = 3;

  // My attempt on iteration
  for(map<pair<int,int>,int>::iterator it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

How do I have to modify the `cout` line, so that it works?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: What is your question? (BTW: There is no overload taking `ostream&, pair<X,Y>`.) Works when printing `it->first.first` instead: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/686ef9dc8e2f05c0

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I want to iterate over keys and print them.

Comment: As an aside, a range-for would be nicer: `for(auto&& x : my_map) cout << x.first.first << ' ' << x.first.second << '\n';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, map Key is first item, but itself it is a pair

So

```
pair<int,int>& key(*it);
cout << key.first << " " << key.second << "\n";
```

might do the trick

Answer (score 5):

`it->first` is an object of type `const std::pair<int, int>` that is it is the key. `it->second` is an object of type `int` that is it is the mapped value. If you want simply to output the key and the mapped value you could write

```
for ( map<pair<int,int>,int>::iterator it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it ) 
{
    cout << "( " << it->first.first << ", " 
                 << it->first.second 
                 << " ): "
                 << it->second
                 << std::endl;
}
```

Or you could use the range-based for statement

```
for ( const auto &p : my_map )
{
    cout << "( " << p.first.first << ", " 
                 << p.first.second 
                 << " ): "
                 << p.second
                 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to c++11, the auto keyword can make it look a lot nicer. I compiled and ran this fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    int main ()
    {
      map <pair<int, int>, int> my_map;
      pair <int, int> my_pair;

      my_pair = make_pair(1, 2);
      my_map[my_pair] = 3;

      // My attempt on iteration
      for(auto it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first.first << "\n";
      }

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A range based `for` can make it look even better :)

Answer (score 2):

By default, `std::ostream` does not know how to deal with `std::pair`. So, if you want to print your keys, the easiest way is to directly access their two elements, as also shown in the other answers. However, if you have access to [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) features, then you can also use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for iterating over your map as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> my_map{ {{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9} };

    for (auto const &kv : my_map)
        std::cout << "(" << kv.first.first << ", " << kv.first.second << ") = " << kv.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> (1, 2) = 3
>   (4, 5) = 6
>   (7, 8) = 9

If you can use [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), then you can further shorten the code by using [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) 
in the range-based `for` loop as follow:

```
for (auto const &[k, v] : my_map)
    std::cout << "(" << k.first << ", " << k.second << ") = " << v << std::endl;
```

[Code on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a73cef214a1a5641)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map <pair<int, int>, int> my_map;
    pair <int, int> my_pair;

    my_pair = make_pair(1, 2);
    my_map[my_pair] = 3;

    // My attempt on iteration
    for (map<pair<int, int>, int>::iterator it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first.first << "\n";
        cout << it->first.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```